# SQLite, SUM difference between to columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I have a table named `Invoice` as follows:-

```
Cost | Billed
240 | 220
180 | 120
120 | 0
```

I would like to do a SELECT SUM of the difference between Cost and Billed

As such, it should return 200 (20 + 60 + 120). Can someone let me know how I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `SUM` directly:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost-Billed)
FROM YourTable;
```

If any of the columns can be `NULL`, then you can either use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(Cost,0)-COALESCE(Billed,0))
FROM YourTable;
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost)-SUM(Billed)
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: What if Billed is equal to `-` because it is written off.

Comment: @Resurgent well, I assumed that those columns were numeric. If they can be `-`, then please update your question with that information and the data type of each column. We can't guess